# Handling a very long query to avoid Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock'?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, asynchronous, async-await

In a WPF application, I have a query that supposed to get a very heavy data (in the LINQ query below one of `ObjectJson` records is of size 10MB!),

this is the method:

```
public  List<HistoryLog> GetAudits(List<Guid> userIds, DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate, List<string> formNames)
{

     var audits = from h in oContext.TbHistoryLog
                  join o in oContext.TbObjects on h.FormName equals o.ObjectRealName
                  join u in oContext.TbUsers on h.UserId equals u.UserId
                  where userIds.Contains((Guid)h.UserId) && formNames.Contains(o.ObjectRealName)
                  && h.DateUpdated > fromDate && h.DateUpdated < toDate
                  orderby h.DateUpdated
                      select new HistoryLog
                      {
                          UserName = Helper.CurrLang == Helper.SystemLanguage.Arabic ? u.UserAName : u.UserEName,
                          UserCode = u.UserCode,
                          DateUpdated = h.DateUpdated,
                          ObjectCode = h.ObjectCode,
                          JSONClassName = h.JSONClassName,
                          FormName = h.FormName,
                          State = h.State,
                          ObjectJson = h.ObjectJson,
                      };

      return  audits.ToList(); //exception is thrown on this
}
```

I got this exception

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' : 'The CLR has
>   been unable to transition from COM context 0x7d9d408 to COM context
>   0x7d9d350 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination
>   context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or
>   processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact
>   and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory
>   usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all
>   single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait
>   primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump
>   messages during long running operations.'

The application hangs for a minute and then fire the exception.. any help on this? is writing an `async` method the solution for this problem?